# Connection of IR 2110 for grid connected flyback inverter

Tags: mosfet-driver

I hope you all are fine. Before i proceed to my question please refer to the diagram shown below.
[image: Unfolding stage of flyback inverter]

The circuit is basically the unfolding stage of the conventional flyback inverter. There are two switches S1 and S2 that work during positive and negative half cycle of the grid respectively. I am switching both of them at 6o Hz line frequency. Two separate gate drivers IR2110 are used for this purpose. Here are my questions:

1. The gate pulse of S1 is applied with respect to source, which is connected to 110 Vac. In this case, what should be the connection of IR 2110 ground ?
2. For S2 the source is connected with the so called ground of ac source, so should we join it with the IR 2110 ground ?
3. Is it necessary to use isolated power supplies for the biasing of both IR 2110 or we can use one single biasing source for both of them.

Comment: I'm not fine; I grazed my arm checking the temperature of my car's radiator.